# BOTW/TOTK-style hatched highlights? (eevee)

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

This is my first time using this site, and im still a bit of a beginner with Blender but have gotten decent at it. Though im having trouble trying to figure out how to reproduce these hatched highlights seen in the new zelda game.
I figure it is some sort of mask but im having a hard time getting it to only show up when its facing the light, and not appearing in the shadow.

if anyone has any tips that would be super cool.

[image: hatching on the back of the coat]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, but here is some clues:

In their shaders, there are two steps. The first is the classic pbr process and the second is the cell shading effect.

Here is the first step render (coming from this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVP9aeuoACc) )

[image]

It is a specular/roughness map at first.

And then a mystic cell shading effect is applied

I tried to create this effect in EEvEE, check it [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGoz8jnolNE)

[image]